# Types conflict when using GraphQL Code generator (codegen)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-codegen

given the following `codegen.ts`

```
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: 'https://mySchema',
  documents: 'src/**/*.ts',
  generates: {
    'src/apollo/gql/': {
      preset: 'client',
      plugins: []
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

the types generated starting from my `schema.json` are in conflict.
I have a query with the following request:

```
...
account {
          id
          label
        }
...
```

and another query which requires more fields like this:

```
...
account {
          id
          label
          balance
          currencyCode
      }
...
```

the result is:

```
export type PfmBankAccount = {
  __typename?: 'PfmBankAccount';
  balance: Scalars['Float']['output'];
  currencyCode: Scalars['String']['output'];
  id: Scalars['Uuid']['output'];
  label: Scalars['String']['output'];
};
```

which has `balance` and `currencyCode` required

but in another `typename` I get the following structure

```
export type PfmTransactionListQuery = { __typename?: 'Query', pfmTransactionList: { __typename?: 'PfmTransactionList', transactions: Array<{ __typename?: 'PfmTransaction', id: any, madeOn: any, amount: number, currencyCode: string, description: string, category: { __typename?: 'PfmTransactionCategory', code: string, label: string, subcategories: Array<{ __typename?: 'PfmTransactionCategory', code: string, label: string }> }, account: { __typename?: 'PfmBankAccount', id: any, label: string }, merchant?: { __typename?: 'PfmMerchant', id: any, name: string, logo: string } | null, optimizations: Array<{ __typename?: 'PfmTransactionOptimization', title: string, subtitle: string, icon: string, action: PfmTransactionOptimizationAction, url: string }> }>, pageInfo: { __typename?: 'PageInfo', after?: string | null } } };
```

in the above type `PfmTransactionListQuery`, the two `PfmBankAccount` are incompatible. I've been trying using client directive `@client` in `Account` query which doesn't required the other fields. Any other solution?